# Comparing time to time represented by text in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, text, time

I have a problem that I'm trying to figure out for work. Basically I'm trying to compare time. Not time of day, but hours in time format (example: 456:23 meaning 456 hours and 23 minutes). In excel, I have imported two reports, one as staffed time, which comes in as actual time (represented as a decimal, but shown as [h]:mm). The other report is a bit iffy and comes in as text representing time (more or less "h:mm").

Here's the problem: 
I have to subtract one from the other. This works up until I have five digits on in the hours slots. 
Example:
100:34 - 300:43 works.
33432:34 - 44321:45 does not work, it gives a generic error.

I cannot convert the text to actual time because it is represented as more or less a picture of the xx:xx format, and not the represented decimal number. I also cannot convert the time into text as it changes the number represented.

Does anyone know how I can get the larger numbers to work, like the smaller numbers do?

Hopefully this is enough context to figure it out. It's likely something small that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

After some critical thinking, I figured it out:

Excel will let you display time in hours:minutes in quantities over 99999:59:59 if it is calculated by a formula. Thus, if you put your time as text in cell f8, and use this formula =((LEFT(F8,LEN(F8)-3)/24)+((RIGHT(F8,2)))/24/60), it will display correctly.